# How can I display odd numbers 1 to 100 with 5 numbers per line in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to display odd numbers from 1 to 100 as 5 numbers per line but I couldn't.

```c
int main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            if(j%2==1)
            {
                printf("%d ",j);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What issue did you encounter? I don't see anything here that would make you skip to the next line. Also, this will repeat the outer loop 5 times, so all the odd numbers will be printed on the same line 5 times.

Comment: The way I usually do this sort of thing is to have one `for` loop counting the numbers I want to print (1 to 100, in this case), and then a second counter (not a `for` loop) counting up and deciding whether it's time to print a `\n`.

Comment: Like you said 5 line loops. Like 1 1 1 1 1 .......

Comment: Read about the `%` (modulo) operator. It could be very helpful here. Hint: you want to print a `\n` every 5th line. Does it ring a bell?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a couple of ways to do this. You could say "print five odd numbers, then a newline, keep doing that until you hit 100", or "run up to 100, if it's odd then print it, if it's a multiple of 10 print a newline". Once you have the general approach in mind, the loops will come easily.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will pay attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not a C problem. You even should not approach a keyboard until you can make clear in your brain what you have to do.

Let us write it down in plain English:

- you want to print numbers from 1 to 100
- you want only odd numbers (so even ones are to be ignored)
- you want a new line after every fifth number

Now in pseudo code:

```
loop for i from 0 to 100
    if i % 2 == 0 continue loop
    print number
    increment counter
    if counter == 5
        print newline
        reset counter to 0
    end of if block
end of loop block
```

For the above algo to work you must just initialize the counter variable to 0 before starting the main loop.

And now it is time to go back to your keyboard and translate that in C language, but it is not the hard part:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
        // as highest number will be 99 "%3d" would ensure at least 1 space
        // but " %2d" makes the intention more evident
        printf("% 2d", i);
        if (++counter >= 5) {
            printf("\n");
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Other implementations are possible, this one is just a working one. What you should have learned here: a programmer **must** be sure of its algo before thinking about how to code it...

Comment: A better way to ensure a space between numbers is `" %2d"` rather than `"%3d"`. I had to deal with a bug caused by values overflowing the field somebody had set, and `" %2d"` deals with that better than `"%3d"` because it guarantees space to separate fields.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I was lazy and tried to save one character, but you caught me ;-)

Comment: you should write `for(i=1...`

Comment: @Laci: you are right, but OP is a beginner, and loops starting from 0 are more idiomatic in C language. But of course as even numbers are to be ignored, starting at 1 would be a small optimization.

Comment: Why not add `step 2` to the pseudocode and then in the code too?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: To be honest, because I did not think about it :-( Anyway, I see that as an optimization point and this code tries to be as simple as possible. But I have upvoted Laci's answer that uses it.

Comment: A agree with that last previous remark. When breaking down the problem in order, you would think of: how do I get a sequence of odd numbers? Skipping even numbers using % is an implementation, rather than other implementations being an optimisation.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have suggested `i=1` not for optimization, but to be consistent with your pseudocode. Nice, detailed answer anyway, exactly what a beginner needs (I also upvoted it.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this (the shortest code)

```
for(int i=1;i<=100;i+=2){
    printf(" %2d",i);
    if(i%10==9) printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: To be more precise, I think this is the shortest full code which is not very nice and hard to read, but can be compiled on a C compiler with several warnings and no program arguments are allowed: `main(i){for(;i<100;i+=2)printf(i%10<9?" %d":" %d\n",i);}`

Comment: Sound like [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is the site for you

Comment: The code in your comment has not been valid C according to the current standard at any time during the current millennium.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It seems that I am too old. I was surprised that I can compile it with `gcc -std=c17` without any error, but why?

Comment: Which version of GCC?  It actually doesn't matter much; GCC doesn't work to standard C by default.  The `-std=c17` should generate warnings from any version of GCC that recognizes C17.  GCC 11.2.0 generates 4 warnings for the code with only the `-std=c17` option specified.  Remember, when a compiler deigns to give you a warning, it has spotted a bug but is so kind and benevolent that it doesn't just give up on your code but attempts to produce something.  But you shouldn't risk that.  The code in your first comment is not valid, modern C (meaning from C99 onwards it is invalid as standard C).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the explanation and info. I have also used tried it on gcc 11.2.0

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it's readable for beginners.

```
int main() {
    int j;
    int k;
    for(j=0;j<100;j++) {
        if(j%2==1) {   
            k++;
            printf("%d ",j);
            if (k == 5) {
                printf("\n");
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    }
return 0;

}
```

or this

```
int main() {
    int j;
    int k;
    for(j=1;j<100;j+=2) {   
            k++;
            printf("%d ",j);
            if (k == 5) {
                printf("\n");
                k = 0;
            }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `k` is not initialized.

Comment: generally, u r right, but it's just a pseudo solution.
10x for the note.

Comment: You're right but first and last line has 4 numbers. if we say int k=0; we will solve